# Need help in using mysql with nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi just now i have installed mysql for nodejs in my windows machine. What is the default username and password for this. And how to see the databases available? Is there anything like phpmyadmin to see the dbs and tables in node? I didn't get any good explanation for this by Googling. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want GUI ? if yes then use Mysql GUI tool here from you can download it for windows

http://mysql-gui-tools.softpedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

The default username for MySQL is `root` and the password is not set. Set the password as soon as possible.

As for GUI's, you could use an offline GUI for MySQL like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) or [Webyog](https://www.webyog.com/). I find it easier to use a non-HTTP interface as it feels a bit less clunky.

If you want to start accessing your MySQL databases for use in your Node application, use the [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module. This is a library for making communication with MySQL easier from Node.

If this is your first time using Node then I recommend getting to grips with some of the basic functionality first. Understanding its modular approach is key to writing good applications.

Comment: But how to configure this with nodejs?

Comment: @Udhay you don't 'configure' MySQL with Node per se. MySQL has its own process listening to its own port, so you simply communicate with it from within your Node application. Or, if you'd like to play with MySQL from a development standpoint, then you can communicate with it via an offline GUI like one of the ones I've suggested. For communicating with it from within your Node app, you should use [node-sql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) which simplifies the functionality a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.conn = require('mysql').createConnection({

  host : 'localhost',  /// mysql host
  user:     "****",   /// mysql username
  password: "***",   /// mysql password
  database: "db_name"

});

var queryString='SELECT * FROM .........';
conn.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) { 
               .........................
           }else {
               ............................
           }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

MySQL for NodeJS is a library not an application. Since it's a library it was intended for programmatic use in your applications.

If you waned an application which allows you to admin your databases using NodeJS then probably [express-admin](https://github.com/simov/express-admin) would be what you are looking for.

express-admin is an application built using NodeJS and using the MySQL library for NodeJS.

Comment: I don't think anybody was suggesting that node-mysql was a GUI.

Comment: Quoting OP: "Is there anything like phpmyadmin to see the dbs and tables in node" I think there is *some* confusion so I cleared it up.